# Converting PDF to PureEdge and modifing the PureEdge form

Tags: pdf, xfdl

I have been looking for a program to convert PDF files (both types) to PureEdge, and be able to modify the PureEdge form (like adding a signature block).  I can only find stuff for lotus forms, and was told that files used for PureEdge Viewer were not compatible with lotus forms.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

PureEdge viewer is a program that allows one to view .xfdl documents which were created using IBM Lotus Forms. The two programs are definitely related.